# Why does the word "tortilla" refer to three distinct types of edibles?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, ambiguity

The crisps[BrEn]/chips[AmEn] that are made of corn (and probably not deep-fried) are called *tortilla*:

[image: Mustard yellow, 400g bag of tortilla chips. There is a see through window in the bag, so the chips are visible.]

The wraps with that special taste, are called *tortila*:

[image: A stack of tortilla pancakes, two are leaning against the left hand side, as if they slipped off.]

And then, the omelet-like meal is called *tortilla*!

[image: Tortilla omlette on a circular wooden board with a slice resting on a cake slice. A metal fork is resting on top of the omlette.]

I can understand that the first usage is probably derived from the second, since I saw something saying that frying the wraps, you can make the chips; but the third usage is not related to these two at all.

What's the commonality among these three that has made the English use the same word for all of them? Or is it just a random confusion/carelessness after borrowing the edible + the name from Mexican and Spanish in different periods of time?

Comment: In American English, the topmost item is usually known as a *tortilla chip*. What I can decipher of the text on the packaging in your photo is actually French, which (on this evidence) appears to prefer a slightly different term compared with English.

Comment: Because the Spanish couldn't pronounce [tlaxcalli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortilla#History_of_the_corn_tortilla)?

Comment: @PeterShor But were the English short of words to choose for the English language?

Comment: The omelets are called *tortillas* in Spain, and the flat corn or wheat wraps are called *tortillas* in Mexico. The British just borrowed both words from Spanish, rather than calling one a *Spanish omelet* the way we do in the U.S.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, and that's off-topic to my question. I'm asking about the *English* language that uses the same word for all of these three. My last sentence just implies the difference in Mexican and Spanish usage.

Comment: It's the British who confuse things. Americans call these *tortilla chips, tortillas,* and *Spanish omelets*.

Comment: Presumably, there were Spanish restaurants in England serving *tortillas* before Mexican restaurants started appearing. When you have Mexican restaurants opening, are the Mexicans going to start calling *tortillas*, a staple of their cuisine, something different?

Comment: @PeterShor Well. . . . here in what was once part of the Vice Royalty of New Spain, we actually **do** call them *tortillas españolas* even in English, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: That's the way the cookie crumbles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think on one level it's fairly simple: because the Spanish word for all three is the same, too. The *Diccionario de la lengua española* gives the omelette sense first, with no particular localisation (although it is often called *tortilla española* and [originates from Spain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_omelette)); then the wrap sense, which is localised to Central America, Mexico, Puerto Rico and the Dominican Republic. Tortilla chips (as they are usually called even in British English, in my experience) are just fried corn tortilla wraps, as you say.

The DRAE doesn't give etymologies, but *tortilla* is diminutive of *torta*, which generally refers to a round flatbread but also has [various other local meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torta). It seems that roundness and flat(ish)ness may be all that they have in common.

Getting back to English, I would say that following @Peter Shor's comment, most Brits would also call these tortilla chips, tortillas (or tortilla wraps) and Spanish omelettes, respectively.

Comment: I expect that *tortilla española* is unlikely in the U.K., as that's the Mexican name for the dish that is called a *tortilla* in Spain.

Comment: @PeterShor It really is not a “Mexican” term. It is true that in Spain they normally just called the omelette *una tortilla*, like when you order *una ración de tortilla* or *un bocata de tortilla*, when necessary Spaniards are perfectly content with opposing *tortilla francesa* to *tortilla española*.

Comment: Yes, for clarity, I was not suggesting that British English speakers would say *tortilla española*, just that Spaniards use it to be unambiguous

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish, the suffixs "illo, illa, ito or ita" mean "small". The word TORTA in Spanish comes from old latin meaning a round bread, cake or pie (sweet or savory), so omeletes are also considered tortas o tortillas. When the Spanish established themselves in America (1500) they called the flat bread "small torta"=tortilla.  In Spanish, ALL OVER, tortilla does not mean only the Amerindian flat bread. An egg omelette is called Tortilla de huevos, a spinach omelette is Tortilla de espinaca; a rice cake is Tortita de arroz, etc. Look at these videos from a Mexican cook and a Peruvian cook, two very different countries:
Mexico, egg omelette: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNdm2xdhk9w

Peru:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekNaUjjUL5k

Enjoy! And now you know that torta, tortilla is NOT only the Amerindian flat bread.

Answer (score 1):

The Native American (Nahuatl) name for the flat round bread was tlaxcali. Torta in ancient Latin meant "round bread" sweet or savory so a "cake-like food. When the Spanish saw the Amerindian flat breads they called it tortilla (small flat round bread) - illo, illa, ito, ita is a diminutive suffix.

With time, torta, tortilla, tortita has also come to mean omelets, spongy cakes, flat round breads and other similar foods (think rice cake-tortita de arroz, crab cake-tortitas de cangrejo, etc.) Even in Mexico, an egg omelet is una tortilla de huevos.

Here is a link to a video of a Mexicaa cook preparing a "tortilla de huevo y berenjena" on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/865ZhWiY1f8)
By the way, tortilla chips are called "totopos".
Buen provecho!

Comment: Where are they called “totopos”?